# Scaling an <image> inside a SVG - Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to put a `<image>` tag inside a `<svg>` along with some other elements. Right now IE11 (and below) aren't rendering the `<svg>` correct.

https://jsfiddle.net/f244sg2u/

```css
svg {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="820" height="560" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 820 560">
  <image width="820" height="560" href="https://dummyimage.com/820x560">
    <title>A title</title>
  </image>
</svg>
```

The image should be rendered at 100% width, but instead is shrunken down for some reason.